# What is the optimal position for groupings of odd numbered buttons on a form?

Tags: buttons, design, placement

I have 3 buttons on a form: submit, cancel, and exit.  I used a larger size and topmost position for the submit and put the cancel and exit as smaller buttons below on the left and right respectively.

However, a triangular placement of the buttons doesn't look right as the form is in the center of the page and it has a more vertical look than horizontal.  The triangle placement doesn't seem to fit well design-wise.

I've seen suggestions to use color and size to direct users to buttons, so for this specific case, what is the best practice to position the submit/cancel buttons together, since they function as a group and then the position the exit button in a placement that fits it best as being outside the main functionality, but still part of the form?

The submit is really a calculation button and cancel resets values.  The exit will take the user out of the app back to the other application page where they called the calculation app.

Comment: What do _Cancel_ and _Exit_ do?

Comment: I call the the submit Calculate, just trying keeping it simple in the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ordering of buttons](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ok-cancel-or-cancel-ok/) doesn't matter much as long as you're consistent, according to usability guru [Jakob Nielsen](https://www.nngroup.com). This is particularly true, because different conventions exist across platforms. For instance, Windows places the buttons like <kbd>OK</kbd> <kbd>Cancel</kbd> whereas it's <kbd>Cancel</kbd> <kbd>OK</kbd> on Mac OS X.

But in reality, I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. The problem isn't how you should arrange your three buttons, but rather: do you really need three?

Again, according to Jacob Nielsen's [article on Reset and Cancel Buttons](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/reset-and-cancel-buttons/), the use of a Reset button is very discouraged:

> Reset clears away the user's input on a Web form, but why would people want to do that? The Web is characterized by frequent movement between pages and users rarely encounter the same form twice. Thus, a Web form is almost always cleared when the user sees it. Even when a user revisits a form in a single session, it is usually faster to edit the old data than to erase it and start over.

Also, people might accidentally hit it.

**And just another thing...**

There's no reason to "conform" to certain button naming conventions, per se. If what your button does is to calculate, you shouldn't call it Submit - just call it **Calculate**!

Comment: The Reset and Cancel buttons idea is new to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From a user point of view, I feel the buttons should actually be

> **CALCULATE**  .  **RESET FORM**

with a line below, "**Press Esc to return to main**". Design issues may have other factors to consider, I do not know.